# F1026 File not found: 'System.Actions.dcu'

Tags: delphi, action, system

I have problem to build my project. I am using delphi 2010.

when i try to build my project this error shows up. **"F1026 File not found: 'System.Action.dcu'**

I've tried to find solution for this error, but i can't find anything that really fix this.

any idea?

Comment: Something tells me that Delphi 2010 didn't used `System` scope yet. If I'm right, then you'll need to change `System.Actions` to `Actions` everywhere in your project. But first try to create a plain new VCL project and try to add `System.Actions` to the `uses` clause of its main form. Try to build it. If that fails for the same reason, try to do what I suggested. If that succeed, then Delphi 2010 didn't used `System` scope yet.

Comment: Yes, you right. Delphi 2010 didn't use System scope. I'm going to use XE3.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I am going to assume that the error message actually refers to `System.Actions.dcu` (as per the question title) rather than `System.Action.dcu` (as per the question body). It's always best to use copy/paste error messages so that they are transferred verbatim.

You are using code written to target a later version of Delphi. Not only does Delphi 2010 not have unit scope names, i.e. `System.<unitname>`, but it does not have the `Actions` unit. If memory serves correctly, unit scope names arrived in XE2 and the `Actions` unit in XE3.

The code you are compiling has a unit the uses `System.Actions`. Find that unit and work out where it came from. Then you'll need to work out how to proceed. Can you get a version of code that supports your older Delphi version? Can you port the code to your Delphi version? Can you find an alternative library? Only you can answer those questions, I'm afraid. We cannot give advice at the moment since we do not know anything about the code that is causing you problems.

Comment: This problem occurs if someone edits a form in XE3 or higher because then the IDE will add that unit automatically (when using TActionList I think) and there is no way to prevent it from doing so (even IFDEFing does not work - it will add it again)

Comment: @Teddy are you still struggling